# How to read data for the following fields in nestjs/swagger dto .I am new to nestjs ,Any help is appreciated

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

idProofs = [
{ name: 'PAN Card', number: '22TB12CD', fileName: ['22TB12CD.png', '22TB12CD.png','22TB12CD.png' ] },
{ name: 'Aadhar Card', number: '359821231', fileName: ['359821231.png'] },
{ name: 'Passport', number: 'AT123ZS', fileName: ['AT123ZS.png'] },
];

I don't know how to put this is in my dto. Here i used multipart/form-data for file upload,so other fields
didn't get works .
I used this approach and also defined as class but only getting blank field in json data.How to read this data using swagger dto in nestjs.

```
@Prop()
idProofDetails: [{
name: { type: string },
number: { type: string },
fileName: { type: string }
}];
```

Comment: Please share more details as to what you are doing and what you want to achieve. Share your code if possible.

Comment: @IstiyakTailor i have to read the above mentioned from swagger dto.i tried different methods but didn't work.